# Value matching by row with aggregation

Tags: r, data.table, match

How can I match values between rows while aggregating?

I have this data:

```
library(data.table)
dat<-data.table(group=rep(1,7),code=c("A11",rep("A12",3),"A10","A9","A8"),
               in.out=c(rep("In",4),rep("Out",3)),type=c("car","train","car",rep("train",3),"car"))

  group code in.out  type
     1  A11     In   car
     1  A12     In train
     1  A12     In   car
     1  A12     In train
     1  A10    Out train
     1   A9    Out train
     1   A8    Out   car
```

And I want to match the type, for in.out == 'Out' with the type for in.out == 'In' at each code level for each observation.

For instance, we see that for the observation with code A8, the type (car) matches the type of code A11. On the other hand, for code A10, the type (train) doesn't match with A11. Ideally, I need to create a list of matching flags (0,1),
like so:

```
group code in.out  type  match
     1  A11     In   car
     1  A12     In train
     1  A12     In   car
     1  A12     In train
     1  A10    Out train  0,1
     1   A9    Out train  0,1
     1   A8    Out   car  1,1
```

I have been trying something like:

```
dat[ , match := +(type[in.out=='Out'] %in% type[in.out=='In']),by=.(code)]
```

But the result is not quite correct. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand the logic here. Why are you matching A8 with A11 and A10 with A11? Are you trying to match all the "Out"s to all the "In"? If so, how would your complete desired output will look like?

Comment: Hello, yes the logic is to match the types between In and Out at the code level, that is for each observation. The desired output is a vector of integer as shown above, 0 for a nomatch and 1 for a match.

Comment: Your current data structure will get insanely messy as the number of codes within a group increases. You might want to look at the igraph package for other ways to structure it.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has asked *How can I match values between rows while aggregating?*
The general answer would be *by joining and subsequent aggregation*.

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to find *all* matches between `"Out"`rows and `"In"` rows where `type` is identical. Then the code levels of the `"In"` rows are numbered contiguously and it is checked for levels a match was found.

```
# create numeric observation levels
dat[, obslvl := as.integer(stringr::str_replace(code, "A", ""))]
# order rows for convenience (not required but helps to understand)
setorder(dat, group, lvl)
# store "Out" rows 
dt_out <- dat[in.out == "Out"]
# store "In" rows in separate data.table and number levels contiguously
dt_in <- dat[in.out == "In"][, lvl.rank := frank(lvl, ties.method = "dense"), by = group]
```

> ```
>    group code in.out  type lvl lvl.rank
> 1:     1  A11     In   car  11        1
> 2:     1  A12     In train  12        2
> 3:     1  A12     In   car  12        2
> 4:     1  A12     In train  12        2
> ```

Now we can join both subtables and aggregate while joining:

```
tmp <- dt_in[dt_out, on = .(group, type), by = .EACHI, 
             toString(as.integer(sort(lvl.rank) == seq_len(.N)))]
```

> ```
>    group  type   V1
> 1:     1   car 1, 1
> 2:     1 train 0, 1
> 3:     1 train 0, 1
> ```

`V1` contains the flags whether a match has been found for the first `"In"` level, the second `"In"` level, and so on. The result is used to update `dt_out`:

```
dt_out[, match := tmp$V1][]
```

> ```
>    group code in.out  type lvl match
> 1:     1   A8    Out   car   8  1, 1
> 2:     1   A9    Out train   9  0, 1
> 3:     1  A10    Out train  10  0, 1
> ```

Finally, the result is joined back with the full datset `dat` as requested:

```
dt_out[dat, on = .(group, code, in.out, type, lvl)]
```

> ```
>    group code in.out  type lvl match
> 1:     1   A8    Out   car   8  1, 1
> 2:     1   A9    Out train   9  0, 1
> 3:     1  A10    Out train  10  0, 1
> 4:     1  A11     In   car  11  <NA>
> 5:     1  A12     In train  12  <NA>
> 6:     1  A12     In   car  12  <NA>
> 7:     1  A12     In train  12  <NA>
> ```

---

There is a shortcut versions which just returns the matching `"In"` levels without creating the flags. Perhaps, this helps to better understand the intensions:

```
dt_in <- dat[in.out == "In"]
dt_out <- dat[in.out == "Out"]
dt_out[, matches := dt_in[dt_out, on = .(group, type), by = .EACHI, toString(x.code)]$V1]
dt_out[dat, on = .(group, code, in.out, type)]

   group code in.out  type  matches
1:     1  A11     In   car     <NA>
2:     1  A12     In train     <NA>
3:     1  A12     In   car     <NA>
4:     1  A12     In train     <NA>
5:     1  A10    Out train A12, A12
6:     1   A9    Out train A12, A12
7:     1   A8    Out   car A11, A12
```